# How does A[ B <= 0 ] = 0 work, when A and B are 2D matrices in Python3?

Tags: python, numpy

**A** is a 2D Matrix of say dimensions **n** X **m**.
**B** is a matrix of dimensions  **n** X **1** , with each element in **B** a vstack of dimensions **p** X **1**.

How would `A[ B <= 0] = 0` work in Python3 ?

Comment: Will a specific row of A become zero if and only if all the elements in the vstack in array B are '<= 0' ?

Comment: I guess you are trying to ask about [tag:numpy]? If so, please [edit] the tags (probably remove the chaff with [tag:list] and possibly others).

Comment: "B is a matrix of dimensions n X 1 , with each element in B a vstack of dimensions p X 1" -- so a matrix of size n X p? A vstack isn't an object, it's a function which makes an array, and a 1D array of 1D arrays is a 2D array in numpy. Your question right now seems a little confused.

Comment: That calls `type(A).__setitem__(A, type(B).__le__(B, 0), 0)`. What that actually does depends on `A` and `B`

Comment: @Eric So as mentioned in the question, if both A and B had float values and the shape as mentioned , would a specific row's elements in A become 0, if all the elements of vstack(in B) '<=0' ?